# jQuery preventDefault

Tags: jquery

Hi I have the following code:

```
collapsed.on('click', 'a',function(c) {
    c.preventDefault();
});
```

Collapsed is basically a div element, inside this div there is an anchor tag which as it stands it does not work because of the prevent function. The prevent function needs to be there. Is there a way of getting that anchor tag working inside that div even with the preventDefault function?

Let me know if you need more info.

Comment: Umm.. well you are preventing the default action on the `a` so what do are you expecting to happen?

Comment: what the point of preventing the default if you actually do want it to work defaultly?

Comment: Why does the prevent need to be there?

Comment: I have an accordion with 4 divs. When you click on a closed div it should only expand to be able to view the content. The prevent function is in there because it prevents from going onto another page which would be possible only by clicking one of the inside anchor tags.

Comment: it sounds like something else is broken then?  if you have an event handler on both the link tag and its container, then your probably looking for c.stopPropagation(); rather than prevent default.  Prevent default shouldnt stop the accordion from working but rather stop the page from redirecting.

Comment: I am going to have at look at it, thanks John..

Answer (score 0):

This will send the user on their merry way.

```
collapsed.on('click', 'a',function(c) {
    c.preventDefault();
    window.location = this.href

    /*
      other options include:
      window.location = $( this ).attr( 'href' );
      window.location = this.getAttribute( 'href' );
      window.location = 'http://staticurl.com';
    */
});
```

I suspect you have a design flaw in your markup, though... If you post that, perhaps you can avoid the preventDefault on your links.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved... Instead of applying the click event on "collapsed" which is one of the closed div in the accordion, I applied the click event on the general accordion div.

Thanks guys